# How to optimise the code for very large values of N. (Time Limit: 1.0 sec(s) for each input file , Memory Limit: 256 MB )

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Your task is to construct a tower in  N days by following these conditions:

```
1. Every day you are provided with one disk of distinct size.
2. The disk with larger sizes should be placed at the bottom of the tower.
3. The disk with smaller sizes should be placed at the top of the tower.
```

The order in which tower must be constructed is as follows:

```
1. You cannot put a new disk on the top of the tower until all the larger disks that are given to you get placed.
```

Print  N lines denoting the disk sizes that can be put on the tower on the  day.

```
def Solve (arr):

    maxx =N
    s= []
    ss=[]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if ((arr[i] == maxx) or (maxx in s) ):            
            ss.append(str(maxx) + " ")
            maxx-=1

            for k in sorted(s)[::-1]:
                if(k == maxx):
                    ss.append(str(k)+" ")
                    maxx-=1 
                    del s[s.index(k)]                
            ss.append("\n")            
        else:
            s.append(arr[i])
            ss.append("\n")        
    return ss

N = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
out_ = Solve(arr)

print("".join(out_))
```

Input format:

First line:  N denoting the total number of disks that are given to you in the  N subsequent days
Second line:  N integers in which the  integer " i"  denote the size of`enter code here` the disks that are given to you on the  i th day

Note: All the disk sizes are distinct integers in the range of  1 to N

Output format

Print  N lines. In the i th  line, print the size of disks that can be placed on the top of the tower in descending order of the disk sizes.

If on the  i th day no disks can be placed, then leave that line empty.

```
Constraints:

1 <= N <= 10^6
1 <= Size of a Disk <=N

Sample Input:
5
4 5 1 2 3


Sample Output:
5 4 


3 2 1
```

Explanation:
On the first day, the disk of size 4 is given. But you cannot put the disk on the bottom of the tower as a disk of size 5 is still remaining.

On the second day, the disk of size 5 will be given so now disk of sizes 5 and 4 can be placed on the tower.

On the third and fourth day, disks cannot be placed on the tower as the disk of 3 needs to be given yet. Therefore, these lines are empty.

On the fifth day, all the disks of sizes 3, 2, and 1 can be placed on the top of the tower.

Comment: Given the size of N, you will need to get rid of the obvious O(N^2) loop in your code.

Answer (score 1):

According to your sample inputs and outputs, you know all the sizes in advance. It means that you can sort the array first by decreasing values. Then, you just need to loop through the array to output them (skipping the value if it is the same as the previous one). You can initialize a variable that holds the previous size with a huge value, so that you don't need to check within the loop if it has been initialized (it will only save a constant factor for the execution time, but if speed is a big concern, it's still worth avoiding useless operations withing loops).

The important thing is to think of the number of operations in the worst case (aka worst-case complexity), computed in terms of N. For the performance analysis, sorting an array of n items takes n*log(n) steps in the worst case. It's a bad idea to sort the data at each step of the loop. The sort in python has been optimized a lot, and even if TimSort can be much better when the data are already sorted (linear), your original algorithm complexity is still at least O(n*log(n) + (n-1)²) = O(n²). Sorting everything first, and avoiding the sort within the loop will give you a much faster algorithm, in O(n*log(n)) in the worst case, and O(n) if you are very lucky with the sizes.

Comment: Are you sure of the interpretation of the exercise, and of the expected output? The answer is pretty straightforward. If there is any time constraint about the number of disks you can put every day, the algorithm becomes much trickier.

Answer (score 0):

If you paraphrase the solution as follows, the answer more or less falls out:

> Wheel k can only be placed if wheel k+1 has been placed **and** k has arrived

So a solution in pseudocode:

- Associate each wheel with its arrival day
- Sort by descending wheel size
- You now have a collection `days` of arrival days.
- Let `now`=0
- While `days` is not empty:

  - If `now < days[0]`: you cannot place a wheel today. Print an empty line. Increment `now`.
  - If `now >= days[0]`: you can place the next biggest wheel. Remove the first element of `days` and loop again.